# Why are CFG80211 symbols missing when loading a kernel module?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, wifi, yocto

I have been given wireless driver which I have integrated in my Yocto project. The `.config` that the kernel is using has the following flag set:

```
CONFIG_CFG80211=m
```

This should compile the kernel with `CFG80211` as a module. However, when I try to load `MY_MODULE`  with this command:

```
insmod MY_MODULE.ko fw_name=mrvl/MY_MODULE.bin cfg80211_wext=0xf cal_data_cfg=none fw_serial=0
```

The module fails to load with:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module MY_MODULE.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

The reason of the failure is that CFG80211 symbols are not present when loading the module. This can be seen when running `dmesg`:

```
[ 1534.508504] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol mlan_main_process (err 0)
[ 1534.508560] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err 0)
[ 1534.508704] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_assoc_resp (err 0)
[ 1534.508847] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err 0)
[ 1534.508911] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err 0)
[ 1534.508948] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol mlan_shutdown_fw (err 0)
[ 1534.509037] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol mlan_rx_process (err 0)
[ 1534.509064] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err 0)
[ 1534.509077] sd8xxx: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cac_event (err 0)
...
```

I tried to manually load the CFG80211 module but it is not present in the `lib/modules/3.14.55-yocto-standard/kernel/net` folder. Currently available modules in those folder are:

```
./kernel/net/wireless
./kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_tkip.ko
./kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_ccmp.ko
./kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
./kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_wep.ko
```

Why are `CFG80211` symbols missing when loading a kernel module? Should I have a loadable 80211.ko  or I am missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yocto does not ship kernel modules by default. You can include all kernel modules in your image by adding `kernel-modules` package. This is usually done within `MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS` or `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS` in your machine conf file, so that people can say they actually don't want all kernel modules (it can take a lot of storage space).

If you want to include this module, its name is probably `kernel-cfg80211` (you can find out by using `oe-pkgdata-util find-path cfg80211.ko`). Since it's needed for another module, I'd add it to `MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS` or `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS` still in your machine conf file.

You cannot realistically add it to the `RDEPENDS` of your other kernel module recipe because it would break your build if someone were to compile 80211 support directly in the kernel and not as a module. Other solution is to use `RRECOMMENDS` in the module recipe or put it where your kernel module package is added to the image (in the image recipe or wherever it's added).

Comment: You pointed me out in the good direction. The problem was that ```MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS``` was populated by using ```bb.utils.contains``` functions. For some reason I needed to add a space between the "wifi" word and the apostrophe in the following line: ```MACHINE_FEATURES_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('MY_MODULE_FLAG', 'true', ' wifi', '',d)}"``` to actually include the cfg80211 module. I am now able to load the cfg80211 module and then my module.

Comment: Hi Ricard, the `_append` "operator" does not add a leading space and most variables expect a space separated list of strings, hence the space you had to add before `wifi`.